# React Ant design Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My app runs successfully but I am getting this error on browser console after using a few components of ant design.
When I installed the ant d I done these steps

- npm install antd
- added link tag of antd.compact.min.css to index.html
- added script tag of /antd/4.13.1/antd.min.js to index.html
- added script tag of /antd/4.13.1/antd-with-locales.min.js to index.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
    at index.js:165
    at Module.a.m.i (index.js:14)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.a.m.i (index.js:25)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.a.m.i (antd.min.js:23)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at universalModuleDefinition:9
    at universalModuleDefinition:1
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.3",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "antd": "^4.13.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-hook-google-maps": "0.0.3",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried `import React {Component} from "react"; and  import * as React from 'react';` but not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Firstly, if you are familiar with HTML CSS and JS structure and using UI libraries(antd ,bootstrap ,semantic UI) like I used to be, this problem could meet you to when you passed to frameworks like Reactjs.

Point is, no need to add CDN links `<link> and <script>` to your index.html file (if documentation does not says to add).
These steps are enough,(example for ant design UI library)

also this link [Use in create-react-app](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) says same

- npm install antd
- `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';` to App.css
- and add `import { Button } from 'antd';` to top of your component when using a ant design component such as button

Conclusion, this error occurs when add  and  tags to react app's index.html

Comment: Yes, one usually adds "script" and "link" tags (for libraries) to their HTML files when they are not using bundler like "webpack" (, and are just using plain HTML, CSS, JS files to create a web app). Libraries added through "script" becomes available to the user directly in the global object.